Maintain active state for exactly one of conflicting units with systemd
I want to unmount some of my local partitions when computer goes to hibernation aka suspend-to-disk. And (of course!) mount them on resume. Consider my mount unit:
[Unit]
Description=Some partition
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target hibernate.target
Before=umount.target hibernate.target
After=local-fs-pre.target

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID>
Where=/mnt/point
Options=defaults

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Technically I want my machine to be in either state:

mount unit is active
reaching hibernate target (or in general conflicting unit is running)

My computer hibernates as of follows:
Reached target sleep.target
Starting systemd-hibernate.service - System Hibernate...
<kernel saves / restores state>
Finished systemd-hibernate.service - System Hibernate.
Reached target hibernate.target - System Hibernation.
Stopped target hibernate.target - System Hibernation.

So mnt-point.mount should conflict with either hibernation.target or systemd-hibernate.service. In example I'm using the former as it looks more idiomatic (just like mount unit implies conflict with umount.target). But in theory hibernation.target is reached only on resume, so it may be safer to stick with systemd-hibernate.service as conflicting unit. That's not really important choice as of now.
The Conflicts= solves only first part of the problem. I'm able to stop mount unit when hibernate. But I'm not able to start mount unit when hibernation ends.
The systemd.unit manual states about Conflicts=:
If a unit has a Conflicts= setting on another unit, starting the former will stop the latter and vice versa.

It looks like vice versa equals to starting the latter will stop the former, but I additionally need stopping the latter will start the former semantics. And I was not able to find any systemd clause to help me with that.
I don't believe there is no idiomatic way to do this as systemd dependency machinery looks quite sophisticated, so maybe someone could point me in the right direction. Maybe we could just ExecStop(Post?)= in systemd-hibernate.service but this is way too generic, one can run arbitrary command with that. Also it is desirable not to override pre-packaged systemd unit when adding every next mount.
